# Why the java.awt.Graphics class is abstract in java?

Tags: java, awt, abstract-class

The class java.awt.Graphics is abstract. Is there any valid reason to
make it abstract ?

Comment: ... who voted to close this as "a simple typographical error"? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

Because having a contextless concrete Graphics class doesn't make sense.

The Graphics class is abstract so that components using the Graphics class can provide a custom concrete implementation of it that is specific to the component and in cases even platform-specific.

If you are able to create a new Graphics object by invoking:

```
Graphics g = new Graphics();
```

to where is the draw/fill methods painting to? How are they implemented? And what purposes do they serve?

Each class that uses the Graphics class (examples include: [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), [BufferStrategy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html), [Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html)) provides a custom implementation that makes sense in their respective context.

A BufferedImage for example, as the name implies, could draw upon a raster maintained in main memory whilst a VolatileImage could draw directly into VRAM (implementation-specific).

The reasons for the abstract class approach with (relatively) hidden custom implementations forms the basis of the concept of the API, something that allows you as the programmer to write code that is portable across platforms/revisions, without worrying about the specifics of the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you should know the concept of abstract classes. When we know implementation but not completely(partially).There we can have concrete method as 
well as abstract method.Same case is with java.awt.Graphics where user can provide his own method as well as can provide specific implementation of method defined in java.awt.Graphics.
See documentation here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html

Answer (score 1):

> What is an Abstract Class ?

Actually abstract class is a class that is declared abstract —it may or may not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.

The Graphics class is the abstract base class for all graphics contexts that allow an application to draw onto components that are realized on various devices, as well as onto off-screen images.